# Linking the SKS file to a Custom Class in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I'm new to Swift and I am trying to code a simple game using `SpriteKit`.

I'm trying to create a main menu page for the 'start' button.

I made a `.sks` file and `.swift` (cocoa touch class) files with the same name.

I designed the `.sks` as I want it to be, but the cocoa touch class is not working.

.swift code:

```
import SpriteKit

class MenuScene: SKScene {

    var mStartBtn: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode()
    var mLabel: SKLabelNode = SKLabelNode()

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        mStartBtn = self.childNode(withName: "startBtn") as! SKSpriteNode
        mLabel = self.childNode(withName: "label") as! SKLabelNode
        mLabel.text = "Hello.."
    }
}
```

I tried to change the label on the screen to see if its working, but it won't change, as if the .swift file is not working/connected to the .sks file.

Comment: Is `didMove` even called?

Comment: no, and I don't understand why. I even tried to put a breakpoint in the class but nothing happened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you suggested, the SKS file is probably not linked to the swift file.

In Xcode

- open the `sks` file
- select your scene
- open the right side panel
- open the `Custom Class Inspector`
- type `MenuScene` into the `Custom Class` field

[image]

Then try again.

Comment: Thanks, I did, but still, the label text won't change.

Comment: I found it, It should be the one item right to the Attribute Inspector, There should be the .swift file name.

Comment: @swiftnewbie Oh yes, my fault. You are right it's the `Custom Class Inspector`. I just updated my answer.